# display only plotted data in the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, z = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col = z)) + geom_line() + geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 2.5))
```

[image]

Only data from the `a` bucket is displayed, yet both `a`, and `b` appear in the legend. How can I fix this, so that only the bucket that is actually plotted appears in the legend?

For context - I'm encountering this while trying [zooming into plots](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html) in `shiny`.

Comment: If you have points outside the visible plotting area, which is the case after zooming, then showing all different point classes is default behaviour.

Comment: @Heikki haha, ok, it's not desired by me - thus the question

Comment: you could use what's returned by `shiny` to filter the data rather than specifying it using `coord_cartesian`

Comment: `df %>% filter(between(x, 1,2)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x, y, col = z)) + geom_point()`

Comment: @bouncyball/dmik3kno Thanks! That's very close to what I want. The only wrinkle (which I only realize now after your suggestion) is that I'm actually plotting lines, and if possible I'd like to keep the lines going in/out of the zoomed in area. I've update the plot in the question - the line I'd like to keep is the small one at the right edge of the plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does filtering on `z` cover your actual use case? For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, z = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'))

ggplot(df %>% filter(z %in% z[between(x,1,2.5)]), 
       aes(x, y, col = z)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 2.5))
```

Or in a function that could be further generalized for user-entered aesthetic variables. (I've also updated the function to use interpolation to plot lines even in plot regions that contain no data points, so long as at least one connecting line between points passes through the plot region.)

```
my_plot = function(xrng, data=df, step=0.01) {

  levs = unique(data[["z"]])  
  n = length(levs)

  # Generate interpolated data frame so we can plot lines even if 
  # no points appear in the graph region 
  dat_interp = split(data, data$z) %>% 
    map_df(function(d) {
      x = seq(min(d$x), max(d$x), step)
      data.frame(z=rep(unique(d$z), each=length(x)),
                 x, y=rep(approx(d$x, d$y, xout=x)$y, n))
    })

  ggplot(dat_interp %>% filter(z %in% z[between(x,xrng[1],xrng[2])]), 
         aes(x, y, col = z)) + 
    geom_point(data=data %>% filter(z %in% z[between(x,xrng[1],xrng[2])])) +
    geom_line() + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = xrng) +
    scale_color_manual(values=setNames(hcl(seq(15,375,length=n+1)[1:n],100,65), levs))
}


gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  my_plot(c(1,2.5)),
  my_plot(c(1,4)),
  my_plot(c(3,4)),
  my_plot(c(4.3,6)),
  my_plot(c(1.1,1.6)),
  my_plot(c(4.2,4.9)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! After some clicking around - this doesn't cover the `my_plot(c(1.1, 1.6))` case, but it's a good enough solution for me.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use interpolation to deal with the case of no data points in the plot region.