# ggplot2: Make the legend display only the visible data series when scaling x-axis with "limits = "

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have timeseries data in which not all the series are fully populated for each date. When I scale the x-axis in such a way that some series display no visible data, I still get legend entries for these series. Is there an easy way to remove these legend entries, or do I have to remove them manually for each chart?

I could create a new dataframe by selecting data series that contain only numeric values, then call ggplot, but I would like to do it all inside the call to ggplot.

Sample data:

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1493856000, 1493942400, 1494028800, 1494115200, 1494201600, 1494288000),
                                       class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
                                       tzone = "UTC"),
                      T1 = c(17.7, 23.5, 31.2, NA, NA, NA), 
                      T2 = c(11.4, 15.9, 20.9, 24.3, 15.5, 16.9), 
                      T3 = c(11.2, 16.1, 21.4, 24.7, 15.2, 16.5)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Create the initial plot with all data:

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  gather(Sensor, Temp, 2:4)

myplot <- ggplot(dat, aes(Date, Temp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(Sensor))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Sensor))) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Temp, C", 
       color = "Sensor") 

myplot
```

[image]

Next I scale the x-axis to limits within which T1 data are all NA. The legend still shows T1 entry and I would like to magically remove that.

```
myplot <- myplot +
  scale_x_datetime(limits = c(as.POSIXct("2017-05-06"), as.POSIXct("2017-05-09")))

myplot
```

[image]

Comment: not sure if this solves your problem but you can select the colours to be displayed in the legend using `lims`. eg `lims(color = c('T2','T3'))`

Comment: @Chris  Your suggestion works! But again, I have to select the series based on prior knowledge of which series has data displayed on the chart. Anything that does this automatically?

Comment: If you want it to be automatic, why not do the automation on the data itself before creating the plot by using `filter` for the dates you want in your plot?

Comment: @Chris - my dataset is large and I am selecting many date ranges to make plots from. So it seems that I would have to create a new dataframe for each plot if I did the limiting before calling ggplot?

Comment: well currently don't you have to write a new `scale_x_datetime` for each plot? Either way you are doing extra manual work.

Comment: @Chris  Sure, but I can automate that part easily by creating a set of date ranges - one pair for each plot. My actual call in scale_x_datetime uses a variable, not a hard-set date. I would have to go examine each plot and update the code for it.

Comment: Does this answer help: [display only plotted data in the legend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983511/8583393) ?

Comment: @EricKrantz perhaps you could update your question with an example of how your variables are set up and passed to `scale_x_datetime`? I don't understand why you can't pass those same variables to a filter - `dat %>% filter(Date >=upper, Date < lower)) %>% ggplot()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 2017-05-06 as the start date, there is one non-NA T1:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(Sensor, Temp, 2:4) %>% 
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2017-05-06") & Date <= as.Date("2017-05-09")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Temp)) 


       Date Sensor Temp
1 2017-05-06     T1 31.2
2 2017-05-06     T2 20.9
3 2017-05-07     T2 24.3
4 2017-05-08     T2 15.5
5 2017-05-09     T2 16.9
6 2017-05-06     T3 21.4
7 2017-05-07     T3 24.7
8 2017-05-08     T3 15.2
9 2017-05-09     T3 16.5
```

therefore producing:

```
df %>% 
  gather(Sensor, Temp, 2:4) %>% 
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2017-05-06") & Date <= as.Date("2017-05-09")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Temp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Temp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(Sensor))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Sensor))) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Temp, C", 
       color = "Sensor")
```

[image: Graph1]

Changing the start date to 2017-05-07 where all T1 values are NA produces this:

```
df %>% 
  gather(Sensor, Temp, 2:4) %>% 
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2017-05-07") & Date <= as.Date("2017-05-09")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Temp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Temp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(Sensor))) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Sensor))) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Temp, C", 
       color = "Sensor")
```

[image: Graph2]

Comment: Thanks. As @Chris suggested, I guess I need to filter before calling ggplot. Was hoping for an easy way to change the default behavior.